# Reading lines and raw bytes from the same source in scala

Tags: scala, io

I need to write code that does the following:

1. Connect to a tcp socket
2. Read a line ending in "\r\n" that contains a number N
3. Read N bytes
4. Use those N bytes

I am currently using the following code:

```
val socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port)
val in = socket.getInputStream;
val out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream)

val reader = new DataInputStream(in)
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)

out.print(cmd + "\r\n")
out.flush

val firstLine = reader.readLine.split("\\s")

if(firstLine(0) == "OK") {
  def read(written: Int, max: Int, baos: ByteArrayOutputStream): Array[Byte] = {
    if(written >= max) baos.toByteArray
    else {
      val count = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
      baos.write(buffer, 0, count)
      read(written + count, max, baos)
    }
  }

  read(0, firstLine(1).toInt, baos)
} else {
  // RAISE something
}

baos.toByteArray()
```

The problem with this code is that the use of `DataInputStream#readLine` raises a deprecation warning, but I can't find a class that implements both `read(...)` and `readLine(...)`. `BufferedReader` for example, implements `read` but it reads Chars and not Bytes. I could cast those chars to bytes but I don't think it's safe.

Any other ways to write something like this in scala?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to change your approach a bit, but Netty (http://netty.io/) provides some great features for reading response streams (like LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder) that would accomplish a lot of what you want to do with very little work.  The only change is that you are dealing with an async (and non blocking) API as opposed to a synchronous (and blocking) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is the best solution I can find:

```
val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
val buffer = new Array[Char](1024)

out.print(cmd + "\r\n")
out.flush

val firstLine = reader.readLine.split("\\s")

if(firstLine(0) == "OK") {
  def read(readCount: Int, acc: List[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
    if(readCount <= 0) acc.toArray
    else {
      val count = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
      val asBytes = buffer.slice(0, count).map(_.toByte)

      read(readCount - count, acc ++ asBytes)
    }
  }

  read(firstLine(1).toInt, List[Byte]())
} else {
  // RAISE
}
```

That is, use `buffer.map(_.toByte).toArray` to transform a char Array into a Byte Array without caring about the encoding.

Comment: this can be safe, because all encodings that are used today are a superset of the 7 bit ASCII encoding. So you can check with char.isValidByte, weather it is safe to transform to a byte or not. Only ASCII letters can be transformed to Bytes.

Answer (score 3):

be aware that on the JVM a char has 2 bytes, so "\r\n" is 4 bytes. This is generally not true for Strings stored outside of the JVM.

I think the safest way would be to read your file in raw bytes until you reache your Binary representation of "\r\n", now you can create a Reader (makes bytes into JVM compatible chars) on the first bytes, where you can be shure that there is Text only, parse it, and contiue safely with the rest of the binary data.

Comment: I really wanted to avoid writing my own BufferedReader that reads until \r\n.

Comment: then you should avoid mixing binary with Text.

Comment: I am not mixing. I am reading this data from a remote server I dont control.

Comment: If you can't avoid the mixing of binary with text, then you shouldn't avoid the burden to separate it safely again.

Answer (score 2):

You can achive the goal to use read(...) and readLine(...) in one class. The idea is use BufferedReader.read():Int. The BufferedReader class has buffered the content so you can read one byte a time without performance decrease.

The change can be: (without scala style optimization)

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.PrintStream
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.Socket
import java.io.InputStreamReader


object ReadLines extends App {
  val host = "127.0.0.1"
  val port = 9090
  val socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port)
  val in = socket.getInputStream;
  val out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream)

//  val reader = new DataInputStream(in)
  val bufIns = new BufferedInputStream(in)
  val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bufIns, "utf8"));

  val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)

  val cmd = "get:"
  out.print(cmd + "\r\n")
  out.flush

  val firstLine = reader.readLine.split("\\s")

  if (firstLine(0) == "OK") {
    def read(written: Int, max: Int, baos: ByteArrayOutputStream): Array[Byte] = {
      if (written >= max) {
        println("get: " + new String(baos.toByteArray))
        baos.toByteArray()
      } else {
//         val count = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
        var count = 0
        var b = reader.read()
        while(b != -1){
          buffer(count) = b.toByte
          count += 1
          if (count < max){
              b = reader.read()
          }else{
            b = -1
          }
        }
        baos.write(buffer, 0, count)
        read(written + count, max, baos)
      }
    }

    read(0, firstLine(1).toInt, baos)
  } else {
    // RAISE something
  }

  baos.toByteArray()
}
```

for test, below is a server code:

```
object ReadLinesServer extends App {
  val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090)
  while(true){
    println("accepted a connection.")
    val socket = serverSocket.accept()
    val ops = socket.getOutputStream()
    val printStream = new PrintStream(ops, true, "utf8")
    printStream.print("OK 2\r\n")   // 1 byte for alpha-number char
    printStream.print("ab")
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the bytes can contain invalid utf8 chars. So this might throw exceptions when converting those bytes to utf8, since the input I read from the socket can be anything, not just text. If I trusted the input I could write something like https://gist.github.com/simao/5618348 that uses mkString and getBytes to convert from a Char Array to a Byte Array.